# Using the Material Theme colorPrimary status bar won't change

Tags: android, android-studio, statusbar, android-appcompat, material-design

So I set in my theme:

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/indigo_50</item>
```

nothing has changed , why?

I know that:

```
On older platforms, AppCompat emulates the color theming where possible. At the moment this is limited to coloring the action bar and some widgets.
```

but:
In this application works without problems:

[image: the AppCompat lib will color status bars on Android 4.0]

and myApp:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need import:

```
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
```

and next add this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
                w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
                w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
}
SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
// enable status bar tint
tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
// enable navigation bar tint
tintManager.setNavigationBarTintEnabled(true);


 // set a custom tint color for all system bars
 tintManager.setTintColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
```

If you want to change status bar color as written in
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)